# CentOS - lm_sensors installation

Tags: centos, kickstart, linux

I need to install CentOS 5 server using kickstart installation.
As part of the installation, I need to install lm_sensors package.
When I'm installing lm_sensors manually, I'm running sensors-detect command.
But this command is requires an interaction with user.

What I need to do in order to make fully automatic CentOS installation with lm_sensors?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use a `%post` script for this:

```
%post --log=/root/sensors-detect.log
yes | sensors-detect
```

[This thread](http://lists.lm-sensors.org/pipermail/lm-sensors/2005-October/013931.html) at the lm-sensors mail list discusses this very issue. Piping `yes` seems to work, although it may not be the cleanest option.

Answer (score -2):

yum install lm_sensors

yum install lm_sensors-sensord

sensors-detect

watch -d sensors

service sensord start

Then refer to http://linux.die.net/man/8/sensord

Comment: http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer